# How to combine a 3D surf plot and a comet3 plot in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm writing a code to plot the circular orbit of a satellite (created using comet3() function) around a 3d model of the Earth (created using surf() and set() functions). The problem is that I can't seem to find a way to get them together in the same plot. I have tried using hold on and hold off but that doesn't seem to work either. I'm pasting the MATLAB code below for reference.

Edit: All the other functions like sv_from_coe(), odeset, etc. are working perfectly, the only place I'm facing issue is combining the plots from comet3() and set().

```
G = 6.67E-11;
Me = 5.976E24;

coe = [6776, 0.0005638, 2.0543, 0.9, 5.549, 0];
[r, v] = sv_from_coe(coe);
rv = [r v];

opt = odeset('RelTol', 1e-6, 'AbsTol', 1e-6);
[t,X] = ode45(@rate, [0 2*1.5*3600], rv, opt);

[x,y,z] = sphere;
r_earth = 6378*1000;

figure
hs1 = surf(x*r_earth,y*r_earth,-z*r_earth);
cdata = imread('1024px-Land_ocean_ice_2048.jpg');
alpha = 1;

hold on
axis equal
comet3(X(:,1), X(:,2), X(:,3))
set(hs1, 'FaceColor', 'texturemap', 'CData', cdata, 'FaceAlpha', alpha, 'EdgeColor', 'none')
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Can you add some more detail to your question? What does the figure that you obtain currently look like, and what would you like to see different?

Comment: @rinkert - I'm currently getting a 3d sphere without the surface image of the earth and after 3 seconds the image of the earth appears. What I want to get is the 3d model of earth, with a satellite orbiting around it in a circular orbit.

Comment: The sv_from_coe() function here takes in the 'classical orbital elements' and outputs initial conditions s (position vector) and v(velocity vector) of the orbit. But all of that isn't a problem. The only place I'm facing an issue is combining the plots from comet3() and set().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to reverse the order, first plot the earth and set the texture. Then use `comet3` to animate the trajectory:

```
% earth
[x,y,z] = sphere;
r_earth = 6378*1000;

% some simple trajectory
phi = 0:0.01:2*pi;
r_orbit = r_earth + 408*1e3; % ISS orbit height
xv = r_orbit * cos(phi);
yv = r_orbit * sin(phi);
zv = zeros(size(yv));

% draw figure
figure(1); clf;
ax = axes;

% first plot the earth and set texture
hs1 = surf(x*r_earth,y*r_earth,-z*r_earth);
alpha = 1;
cdata = imread("Land_ocean_ice_2048.jpg");
set(hs1, 'FaceColor', 'texturemap', 'CData', cdata, 'FaceAlpha', alpha, 'EdgeColor', 'none')
hold on
axis equal

% finally, animate using comet3
comet3(xv,yv,zv)
```

Comment: Nice example, but may be set the orbit radius slightly above the earth surface (like `r_earth*1.2`). It feels a bit weird to see the satellite surfing the oceans and continents :)

Comment: @Hoki ah right, I thought I did, but I see that I messed up the order in copy pasting... Fixed, thanks for remark :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I tried out your code and it works perfectly, although it still only shows the 3d earth for my code... :( Also, can you explain why have you used clf; and ax=axes in the code?

Comment: @KarthikBalajiM so you only see the earth, and not the output of `comet3` for your data? Can you plot the output of `ode45(@rate, ...` using `figure(); plot3(X(:,1), X(:,2), X(:,3))`? What do you see?

Comment: Regarding the `clf` and `axes`, that's just a habit I guess. I always give my figures a number, and clear them after creation. That way, if I add multiple lines to the plot by setting `hold on`, and then run my script again without a `close all` at the top, the old lines are cleared and I just plot the new lines. And I don't like to use e.g. `gca` since this is dependent of which figure you clicked last, so I mostly define an axes specifically. Not really necessary in this case though...

Comment: @rinkert- The code works perfectly, it's just that I messed up with the dimensions. The 3d earth in my original code was 1000 times bigger than the orbit radius, so I never got to see it. I tweaked the orbit radius and I was able to see it perfectly. :)